# How do I set parameters when calling CPLEX from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cplex

I'm using Matlab to set up an optimization problem and calling CPLEX on it as follows

```
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = cplexqcp(problem);
```

My optimization problem is a qcp. I'm running out of memory so I want to set CPX_PARAM_NODEFILEIND = 2. I tried setting it with

```
options = cplexoptimset('CPX_PARAM_NODEFILEIND', 2)
```

But this just gave an error

```
Error in CVaR_OS_Exact
options = cplexoptimset('CPX_PARAM_NODEFILEIND', 2);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See the [using parameters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/MATLAB/topics/gs_param.html) section in the MATLAB API documentation and [node storage file switch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/NodeFileInd.html) in the parameter reference manual.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
opt = cplexoptimset('cplex'); 
opt.mip.strategy.file=2;
```

Comment: Hi! thx for the response. I tried that setting, but I get a fatal error report in matlab. Any more ideas are welcome